# Smooth Scrolling for absolute positioned contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I am using this [Page scroller.js](http://coliss.com/wp-content/uploads-201303/page-scroller-309/demo-2.html) to give smooth scroll effect to my page.
but it won't work.

Issue for this was that I was targeting the div which had position:absolute;. I still need this div to have position absolute and also have the smooth scroll work.

Here is my Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<nav id="globalNav">
  <h1><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="SHISEIDO" /></a></h1>
  <ul class="subMenu">
    <li><img src="img/seperator.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><a href="#works">TOP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#concept">CONCEPT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><img src="img/seperator.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="img/seperator.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><p class="copyright">Copyright © KOOGEN 2015<br>All rights reserved.</p></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fbFeed">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="col-sm-8" id="left">
  <div class="set">
  </div><!-- set -->
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4" id="right">
    <div id="inner1">
      <div id="works"></div>
      <div id="concept"></div>
      <div id="contact"></div> 
    </div><!-- inner -->
</div>


</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

So, #left #right divs have position absolute to create 3 column layout.
I added anchor link to my globalNav so that when I click, contents inside #right div will scroll smoothly.

heres my css added to #left and #right divs.

```
      #left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 218px;
    width: 186px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45);
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
 #left .set{
  padding-top: 230px;
 }
  #right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 67.5%;
  }
 #right #works{
  padding-top: 230px;
 }
 #right .inner{
  position: relative;
 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you for your time!

UPDATE:
This is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/hirohito/Ls3jwpm9/

It works when the window's width is very narrow, but when I stretch it out to the ideal window size, smooth scroll stop working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for smooth scroll

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var $id = $(id);
        if ($id.size() === 0) {
        return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var pos = $(id).offset().top;
        pos = pos-95;   
        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos});
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I added to my index.html but it's still not working.. Do I need to replace some thing to make it work?

Comment: I've got..."Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ index.html:32"
as an error for the script you gave me.

Comment: please include jquery library file. <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> in head.

Comment: so, anchor link worked after including jquery library link you gave me.(1.11.3). Unfortunately its not doing the smooth scroll animation. I found out that, that page scroller.js works with (jquery-1.3.min.js～jquery-1.6.min.js). How could I get this work?

Comment: can you make fiddle?. and no need to use page scroll.js. above the code enough.

Comment: I added the fiddle to my question. Please take a look!

Comment: set speed and changes this line  $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos},1000);

Comment: thanks for your fiddle!
Ive applied the same and uploaded to test it.
http://1ne-studio.com/test2/index2.html
id:test
pass:2015

and its not working for some reason.. is my CSS doing something bad?

Comment: remove this style #globalNav {position: fixed;}

Comment: So, I did something different. I made the change so that scrolling works.
But div#right is now not scrollable and my background got messed up.
How could I fix this and still have this scrolling available.